# Convert time duration in format of hh:mm:ss [String] to mins

Tags: python, pandas

I have Waiting time in the format hh:mm:ss. I want to convert them to the **waiting mins** [which is the total waiting time in mins]. Some values in the waiting time are 0 or negative values like -1:0:0, -8:9:0 I want to convert them to 0 min.
WaitingTime is a pandas dataframe and the values are Strings.

```
**WaitingTime**
0
0
00:07:20
00:17:42
00:25:25
00:02:05
00:45:19
-1:0:0
-8:16:47
-9:17:43
0
00:15:07
-1:0:0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope I below lines help...

```
import datetime

a_time='-00:05:36'
try:
    given_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(a_time, '%H:%M:%S')
    minuts = given_time.hour*60+given_time.minute+given_time.second/60
    print(minuts)

except ValueError:
    given_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(a_time, '-%H:%M:%S')
    minuts = given_time.hour * 60 + given_time.minute + given_time.second / 60
    print(minuts)
```

below is for pandas with a little workaround, taken different column names for explanation you can overwrite as per your requirement , a hope it will help...

```
import datetime
import pandas

# Taken The waiting time column in excel
myframe = pandas.read_excel('Book1.xlsx',sheet_name='Sheet1')
myframe['NewTime'] = myframe['WaitingTime'].astype(str)
myframe['NewTime_2'] =  myframe['NewTime'].replace('-','', regex=True)

myframe['converted_time2'] = myframe['NewTime_2'].replace(to_replace='0',value='00:00:00')
myframe['converted_time3'] = pandas.to_datetime(myframe['converted_time2'], format='%H:%M:%S')

myframe['minutes']= myframe['converted_time3'].dt.minute
print(myframe['minutes'].head())

myframe.to_excel('output.xlsx', index=False)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But can I use [try except] with pandas dataframe?

Comment: myframe['converted_time'] = pandas.to_datetime(myframe['giventime'],errors='ignore',format='%H:%M:%S').... next..... myframe['time_hour'] = pandas.to_datetime(myframe['converted_time'], errors='ignore').dt.minute.....try this approach I will try to post updated answer soon

Comment: Thank you. The answer is correct it is just that I want the total mins so it is myframe['minutes']=myframe['converted_time3'].dt.hour *60 + myframe['converted_time3'].dt.minute + myframe['converted_time3'].dt.second /60

Answer (score 1):

Quick solution, just checking for the first char to see if it's '-'.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"waitingtime": ["00:23:00", "0", "-1:00:00"]})
>>> df["waitingtime"].apply(lambda x: "0" if x[0] == '-' else x)
0    00:23:00
1           0
2           0
Name: waitingtime, dtype: object
```